# Conditional formatting with reference sheet using INDIRECT, INDEX & MATCH?

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, reference, match, conditional-formatting

How can I rewrite this formula to work in conditional formatting? If the formula returns the value "a", then I want the cell to be formatted green. See an example in the google sheets link below.

=index(Availability!$B$3:$N$8,match(Sales!$A3,Availability!$A$3:$A,0),match(weeknum(Sales!B$2),Availability!$B$2:$N$2,0))

There are 2 sheets in my workbook. I want to apply conditional formatting to a "Sales" sheet based on whether or not there is a corresponding letter at the intersection of an item and a date in another worksheet. In this case, I have a "Sales" sheet with a list of items down column A and a string of dates in columns B-N, and in an "Availability" sheet I have the same list of items ( in a different order) in col A and dates in col B-N (in this sheet, it's actually the week number). So, if in the "Availability" sheet there is the letter "A" at the intersection (B3) of "arugula" and "15" AND in the "Sales" the same item and date are present, I want to highlight the cell green that intersects these two pieces of data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C8bm2Jf4-u_lz3Dt3OlQ1SKQ2uijP0Qcume7akLKqas/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Player0, I just made it public. Try the new link in the edited question above.

Comment: This link should work: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C8bm2Jf4-u_lz3Dt3OlQ1SKQ2uijP0Qcume7akLKqas/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(
 INDIRECT("Availability!B3:N8"), MATCH($A3,
 INDIRECT("Availability!A3:A"), 0), MATCH(WEEKNUM(B$2),
 INDIRECT("Availability!B2:N2"), 0))<>""
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried your formula in the custom formula option in cond. formatting, but it turns every box green. Hmm...

Comment: I added editing option to the sheet if anyone wants to give it a go!

Comment: I reworked your formula and got one box to turn green, but none of the others. =""<>INDEX(INDIRECT("Availability!B3:N8"),MATCH(A3,INDIRECT("Availability!A3:A"),0),MATCH(WEEKNUM(B2),INDIRECT("Availability!B2:N2"),0))

Comment: @OhioFarming you need to lock it with $ see the updated formula/answer